# OpenApi 3.0 anyOf

Tags: openapi

I read previous posts. Looking a stripe OpenAPi3.0 model. Here is a small fragment.
What is the application type? It is recursively referencing itself? x-expansionResources is a vendor extension.

```
 "charge": {
    "properties": {
      "amount": {
        "description": "A positive integer in the [smallest currency unit](https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#zero-decimal) ",
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "application": {
        "anyOf": [
          {
            "maxLength": 5000,
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/application"
          }
        ],
        "description": "ID of the Connect application that created the charge.",
        "nullable": true,
        "x-expansionResources": {
          "oneOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/application"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In this example, the value of the `application` property can be:

- a string up to 5000 characters ("ID of the Connect application that created the charge")
- an instance of the `application` schema
- `null`

In Stripe terms, `application` is an [expandable](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) property. Expandable properties can contain either the ID of the associated object, or a full object. This is what their `x-expansionResources` extension indicates.

Technically, `anyOf` in this example may be replaced with `oneOf`. The subschemas have completely different types (`type: string` and `type: object`) so both `anyOf` and `oneOf` will work. (`oneOf` means "match exactly one subschema", `anyOf` means "match one or more subschemas".)

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the test data, they either send an id(string) or a class. The extensionResource tells it oneOf the classes. In this example there was only one. I don't understand why the model did not just use oneOf in the first place?